# Change the value of input fields, according to what is selected from the Dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I want my form input values to change automatically according to what is selected from the drop down box. 
So I basically have a form with three fields, and a `<select>` tag which has two `<option>` tags, all of this on the same page, so I want the values of those fields inside the form to update dynamically as different option is selected on the select box.

```
<select>
  <option>Cake</option>
  <option>Brownie</option>
</select>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="one"></input>
  <input type="text" name="two"></input>
  <input type="text" name="three"></input>
</form>
```

Basically all the textboxes shoul have the same words of selected option, for example if 'Cake' is selected I want all the textBoxes to display the word Cake, and then if 'Brownie' is selected then all the textBoxes to display Brownie and so forth. Thanks

Comment: Why are you changing the values of the users input? What are you trying to change the values to? Have you tried any javascript? Do you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: You have 3 textbox and 1 dropdown, what values will go to the remaining two? please explain your question further.

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Basically just want all the user input textbox have the same words as on the selection option, so if 'Cake' is selected I want all the textBoxes to display the word Cake, and then if 'Brownie' is selected then all the textBoxes to display Brownie and so forth. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simple javascript solution for the html you've provided:

```js
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var texts = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
     texts[i].value = select.value;
});
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Cake</option>
    <option>Brownie</option>
</select>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="one"/>
    <input type="text" name="two"/>
    <input type="text" name="three"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Solution - Change :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("select#YourSelectId").change(function(){
      var b = $("select#YourSelectId :selected").text();
      $("input.TheInputsYouWantToChange").val(b);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will simply add the selected value to a single textbox. OP has 3 textbox and 1 select. it's not even clear that what he wants to do.

Comment: He wants to dynamically change the value of the inputs based on textbox selection. I think it is clear.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Basically just want all the user input textbox have the same words as on the selection option, so if 'Cake' is selected I want all the textBoxes to display the word Cake, and then if 'Brownie' is selected then all the textBoxes to display Brownie and so forth. Thanks